# Include types from external package to ts output

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have the following code:

```
import { ExampleType } from "@org/package-1
type AnotherType = ExampleType & number
```

I want `ExampleType` to also be included in the types definition output generated by `tsc` command line tool.

The output should look like this:

```
// dist/types.d.ts
type ExampleType = string | boolean
type AnotherType = ExampleType & number
```

I'm using `typescript v4.6.4` and is how my tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
  "include": [
    "./src/types",
    "./src/exceptions",
    "./src/config",
    "./src/index.ts",
    "./src/Client.tsx",
    "./src/Whatever.ts",
    "./node_modules/@org/package1",
    "./node_modules/@org/package2"
  ],
  "exclude": [],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["react", "react/jsx-runtime"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "target": "ES6",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2017",
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist/types",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "noResolve": true
  },
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "final ts output"?

Comment: I meant the output from "npm build". Which is something like this `tsc -p tsconfig.prod.json`

Comment: `tsc` transpiles TypeScript to JavaScript. In JavaScript **types don't exist**.

Comment: Yes, but this is for a library so I need to build the types definitions

Comment: You could just re-export the types

Comment: @catgirlkelly what do you mean? I know there's a rollup plugin that does what I want, but I can't use it here

Comment: @JeanLambert “there's a rollup plugin that does what I want,” could you _link to that?_ Because right now it is not at all clear what you want, and if we could see a working example, possibly with documentation, it might clarify what result you’re hoping to achieve. Because `tsc` will **never** write `type Anything =` in its output; its output is Javascript and that doesn’t have types.

Comment: @KRyan I was confused, couldn't find a rollup plugin that does it. But `tsc` does write `type Anything =` if you're using the right tsconfig.

Comment: @JeanLambert Are you talking about a `.d.ts` file? `tsc`’s (primary) output is a `.js` file, and `type Anything =` would be an error in Javascript.

Comment: Yes, sorry, let me update the post, but I'm talking about the types definition output generated by `tsc`

Answer (score 1):

A module should export the types it wants to expose. It doesn't matter where those types come from. It may be constructed internally by a module, or imported from another module.

There's nothing special about that. Just import the types your module needs, and export the types you want your module to expose.

For example:

```
import { ExampleType } from "@org/package-1" // use in this file

export { ExampleType } from "@org/package-1" // export a type from another module
export type AnotherType = ExampleType & number // use an imported type in an exported type

export type YetAnotherType = { abc: number } // export a totally internal type
```

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: @JeanLambert This is the correct answer to the question you _seem_ to be asking, so again, please clarify what you actually want to achieve, ideally with examples of the code you’re trying to write that references this library and what errors you get when the library is written like this.

Comment: I tried re-exporting the types and they weren't included in the types definition output

Comment: They typescript code that makes those types will not be included in the output of your package. You have to install your package's dependencies in the target environment, and then you package imports types from those and re-exports them along. This should be handled for you by your `package.json` and it should just work.